# Something wrent wrong with the plugin API

Tags: php, wordpress

I've installed Wordpress 5 and configured a virtual host for my local wordpress sites 
I need to install some plugins and when I try to install I get an error message : "Something went wrong with the plugin API." 
Does someone know what is provocating this error ?

Here is a screenshot of my file permissions in the wordpress install root folder 
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've finally found it,

It was a dummy thing, I tried to install my plugins at the same time by checking all the checkbox and use 'install' action. But when I did it one by one I've seen that one plugin is no longer available

If someone got problems one day with this error

Comment: so how did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This can be a lot of things. You can try some of these things:

- Apply correct [File Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions);
- [Manually install the plugin](https://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins#Manual_Plugin_Installation_by_Uploading_a_Zip_Archive);
- Open DevTools and check if some issue appears in the log, as well as enable and read php logs;
- If the plugin requires some API Key/Funcion from another, check if this is correctly enabled and working;

Comment: I've already tried to change file permissions and the error continue to show up, I don't think it's about file permissions, thus I cannot install plugin manually because they come from a premium theme I bought. I'll try with the dev tools and let you know